# custom object lookup relationship soql query to get sobject

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I have 2 custom object.

```
1 - namespace__object1__c
2 - namespace__object2__c
```

I have lookup relationship in custom object namespace__object2__c.

Now i want to query id record from object2 where object1 id = (provided parameter)

```
String s = 'a6T3k0000LMJcEAO';
string query = 'select ID, (select ID from namespace__object1__c where ID = :s  ) from namespace__object2__c';

SObject rObject = database.query(query);
system.debug(rObject);
```

Answer (score 1):

object2 has lookup to object1, right? What's the field name?

```
SELECT Id, Name
FROM namespace__object2__c
WHERE namespace__object1__c = 'a6T3k0000LMJcEAO'
```

should work. Put the right field name in (lookup field typically is but doesn't have to be identical).

Some other things you can do with this (but let's use std. objects in example)

```
SELECT Id, Name
FROM Contact
WHERE AccountId = '001...'

SELECT Id, Name, Account.Name
FROM Contact
WHERE Account.Name LIKE 'Acme%'
```

And even

```
SELECT Id, Name
FROM Account
WHERE Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Contact WHERE LastName = 'Smith')
```